# How to create feature LineString in a Polygon shapefile layer (OGR/GDAL)?

Tags: shapefile, ogr, dgn

I used below codes to create shapefile layer:

```
OGRDataSource       *poDS,  *poSHPDS;
OGRLayer   *poSHPLayer;
...
poSHPLayer = poSHPDS->CreateLayer (shpFileName, NULL, wkbPolygon , NULL);
```

And I used below code to create feature:

```
OGRFeature *poSHPFeature; 
poSHPFeature = OGRFeature::CreateFeature (poSHPLayer->GetLayerDefn());  
poSHPFeature->SetGeometry (poGeometry);
```

But when I tried to add create a LineString feature into shapefile layer. I got the error:

"**Attempt to write non-polygon  geometry to polygon type shapefile**". Please see my image.

[image]

How can I add linestring into layer (shapefile) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to accept the error message :-(

Shapefiles are intended to be point, line or polygon geometries, but not  a mixture of them.

From http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_shapefile.html:

> ESRI shapefiles can only store one kind of geometry per layer (shapefile).

There are other data formats (GML, GeoJSON, KML) which allow that, but you will be getting problems when you want to transform those formats to shapefiles.